# How to pass AngularJS ng-repeat Variable to Javascript click event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parameter-passing, angularjs-ng-repeat

I would like to know how to pass Angular ng-repeat variable to my Javascript onclick event

My angular repeater

```
       <div class="data" data-ng-repeat="sub in subs" >  
            <button onclick="ConfirmDialog(sub.SubID)">Cancel</button>
            {{ sub.someOtherProperty}}
            {{ sub.someOtherProperty}}
            {{ sub.someOtherProperty}}                
        </div>
```

My script function

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    function ConfirmDialog(subID) {
             console.log('Succesfully submitted id: ', subID);
    });
 </script>
```

The error : **sub is not defined** (in the onclick() call from the button element) all other properties show as expected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are running straight javascript onclick instead of ng-click.

move confirmDialog into your controller and ng-click can attach to it.

```
 <div class="data" data-ng-repeat="sub in subs" >  
        <button ng-click="ConfirmDialog(sub.SubID)">Cancel</button>            
 </div>

 $scope.ConfirmDialog = function (subID) {
         console.log('Succesfully submitted id: ', subID);
 });
```

Comment: "Turning into a String" approach won't work , error : Error: [$compile:nodomevents] Interpolations for HTML DOM event attributes are disallowed.  Please use the ng- versions (such as ng-click instead of onclick) instead. 

However, moving it into the controller did +1!

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use ng-click, you still have a chance! Try the following

```
<tr ng-repeat="supplier in suppliers" id="{{supplier.id}}">
       <button onclick="readVariable(this);">
</tr>

<script>
    function readVariable(elem){
        id = elem.parentNode.id;
        console.log(id);  //it works!
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use ng-click instead in order to access the ng-repeat variable

```
<button ng-click="ConfirmDialog(sub.SubID)">Cancel</button>
```

Comment: I'm not passing it back to an Angular controller. Ng-click wouldn't work.

Comment: I think I misunderstood you as you were trying to tell me to move everything into the controller by using ng-click. I was not aware that this is what you meant, so +1.